# Error using mex (g++ error: No such file or directory)

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm trying to compile a library in Matlab (http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/downloads.html) on Windows, using the given `compile` script, but am getting the following error.

```
Error using mex
g++: error: /c: No such file or directory
g++: error:
/FoC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_4354548680745_632\mexArchetypalAnalysis.obj:
No such file or directory


Error in compile (line 456)
    mex(args{:});
```

I'm stuck here. What's going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which version are you trying to install?

Comment: `/FoC:\Users` seems weird

Comment: @Suever: latest version (2.5).

Comment: @AnderBiguri: How can I find the location in the code where it's attempting to access this file?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem in Windows.

Try **changing CFLAGS to COMPFLAGS**. It worked for me.

Source: https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/issues/55

Comment: Please include the necessary contents of the link in your answer, if the link breaks or changes your reference will be useless

Comment: Thanks lbo for your point. I am new here.
"changing CFLAGS to COMPFLAGS" this line is the main point of the link. I just put it as a source.